# Mac Python NameError: name 'get_sum' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

My computer is MacBook pro. I have two .py files. One is functions.py(containing a get_sum()function for test), another is functions_import.py that will import all function of functions.py. .
The Functions.py is:

```
def get_sum(a:int, b:int):
    return a+b
```

The functions_import.py is(ImportStudy is folder name of project just for test):

```
from ImportStudy.Functions import *
import ast
def exec_then_eval(code):
    block = ast.parse(code, mode='exec')
    # assumes last node is an expression
    last = ast.Expression(block.body.pop().value)
    _globals, _locals = {}, {}
    exec(compile(block, '<string>', mode='exec'), _globals, _locals)
    return eval(compile(last, '<string>', mode='eval'), _globals, _locals)

code_string = "result = get_sum(10, 20)\nprint(result)"
output = exec_then_eval(code_string)
```

I just use an exec_then_eval function is to execute a string of code which contains "get_sum()" function imported on top. But after running, it gives me below:

NameError: name 'get_sum' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Try ImportStudy.Functions.get_sum() instead of just get_sum()

Comment: Are you sure? Do you think the parentheses are necessary?

Comment: Try it both ways, I put the parenthesis whatever, the main thing is I put the module before the function name.

Comment: But with parentheses you'll get a syntax error!

Comment: I delete "_globals, _locals" at those 2 places , then is ok.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

delete "_globals, _locals" at those 2 places , then is ok